# How to defend opinion against victim card (Ad Hominem)

Tags: conversations

Edit: I found the term, it is **Ad Hominem**

This frequently happens that when I present the opinion that considers morality as an emergent and highly subjective experience and that at the core of rule of law lies the authority and willingness of the most powerful group of people to impose it, I get charges that I am insensitive to humanity. For example, in a debate with my friend, he said that a country is morally wrong to invade another country since sovereignty should be respected, I replied that sovereignty is not respected as act of charity but only as long as the most powerful actor involved in the case is willing to respect it or the state has the resources to defend its sovereignty.

This is what I have read from texts like Fukuyama's The origins of Political Order and in general history and it seems to be the only practical and self consistent approach towards abstract ideas like morality

But he instead asked that if I am saying that I support killing of innocent people and when this happens, I am forced to take detour from my stand and justify that what I think as a person is not relevant to debate and that he should attack only the content of my ideas and not what my personal beliefs are.

I wanted to ask what is a single term that is referred to such charges that attack personal beliefs instead of the idea presented. After some googling, I found the strawman argument as something like what I described where a general statement is supplemented with a detail that was unspecified by the original speaker and then this spurious detail is used to nullify speaker's claim.

But I am confused if this is the right term because I also sense a circularity in my friend's argument, he is using morality to defend morality while my argument essentially is pointing out that morality is not fundamental so all of his arguments that invoke morality are anyways not interesting to me since I don't lend authority to morality.

One additional issue I spot is that this challenge arises only because he has not presented any hypothesis of his own, for if he had presented his own hypothesis, I could have (reluctantly) charged him with supporting something unacceptable arising from his claim but this is undesirable since both of us will descend to eventual name calling, I want to know a way to quickly exit such situation and return to original debate

Thanks!

Comment: You want a name for "I think there is no such thing as right and wrong, people do what they can and are strong enough for" ? That exists. You want a name for "actually some things are wrong even if strong people are capable of doing them"? That also exists. But you want a name for "I'm arguing the first thing and these stupid pesky victims have the nerve to argue the second thing"? That doesn't have a name, it is a philosophical disagreement. There is no "original debate" there is just your opinion, that right and wrong don't matter. Your friend doesn't accept that premise and doesn't have to.

Comment: @KateGregory, I did not say the victims are stupid or pesky, but this is exactly my point, unless I clarify each time (Detour from original argument) that I also personally care for the victims, it leaves me in a bad reputation and I am not at all asking my friend to accept my position, what I want to mean was each person's standing on any issue can be shown to cause suffering to one group to other, hence what is the term for this where we tell our friend to ignore the consequences that are common in both cases (suffering to some group) and focus on different outcomes of our positions

Comment: Kutsit, it seems you want to debate for the right of the stronger to do what they like. Did it occur to you, from an interpersonal point of view, that anyone you debate with who is stronger than you could also do what they like?

Comment: @gnasher729 that is a fundamental truth in my opinion, debate can only occur between equals as they perceive each other, one can never win a debate with an unequal opponent like parents or teachers since if they try to be unreasonable or rude in their opinion, we can protest up to a certain extent, but cannot abandon basic rules of etiquette. In fact this is a recurring theme in Indian epic Mahabharata where there are many interpersonal relations between unequals, and that is where I first realized that equality can exist only between equals as they perceive it

Comment: Also, @gnasher729, I am not saying they have the right, since rights and duties are designated by a higher authority or decided on mutual agreement, in case of two sovereigns here, there is none, morality could have acted as an authority but i am discarding it so there is not point about talking of rights, instead I am trying to say is that since morality will not be able to broker peace in this case, it is better to look for alternative frameworks that take into account this viewpoint and this may succeed in brokering peace

Comment: Kutsit, you seem not to understand what this site is about. It's not about debating and winning arguments. It's about having to take the other person as they are and getting the best possible outcome for yourself. Anything on this site is not "interpersonal". When we meet face to face it's interpersonal. And the arguments you brought, in an interpersonal situation, would end up painful. "Invading another country" isn't abstract. It's killing. It's rape. It's murder. It is destroying people's life. If you argue for that, face to face with me, you'll pay.

Comment: I may not be understanding what this site is for but I don't like your language in last sentence, I have said it many times it is not me who is supporting something, I am presenting a proposition and simply listing the consequences arising out of it, my personal conduct is cannot be judged from the hypothesis that I present, personally, I too pretend to believe and preach in all good things like you

Comment: This question has nothing to do with interpersonal skills at all. It is about arguments that could be used in a debate to win the argument. An interpersonal question would be asking how to avoid a negative reaction, for example. Or how to walk away from an argument with a friendship or relationship intact. This one doesn't. And the person asking the question doesn't even understand this.

Comment: @gnasher729, I know it is not relevant but since it has already been answered and that person will loose upvotes if I delete, I am waiting for it to be closed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> For example, in a debate with my friend, he said that a country is morally wrong to invade another country since sovereignty should be respected, I replied that sovereignty is not respected as act of charity but only as long as the most powerful actor involved in the case is willing to respect it or the state has the resources to defend its sovereignty.

He's saying it's morally wrong, you're saying it'll happen anyway. However, these two questions are orthogonal: any act can be morally right, wrong, or neutral depending on the act. And it can happen anyway, or not happen. There is no link between the two besides the (supposed) morality of whoever does the act. It's a bit like the is versus the ought.

Therefore you're arguing about two different unrelated things, talking past each other, and not getting anywhere. It's not really a strawman, you're just not debating about the same thing.

> But he instead asked that if I am saying that I support killing of innocent people

Now that could be argument from emotion or something, but I think it's simply that neither of you realized you're talking about different topics.

This happens quite often. Within a friendly debate (ie, when the purpose is NOT to, for example, lie as much as possible to win an election) then it is the responsibility of both participants to spot these and point it out. Whoever does it first earns one brownie point. Unfortunately, in this case, none of you did.

The ideal platform to experience this is, of course, twitter, because the very short character limit makes it difficult to explain one's point in detail, leaving a lot for the other party to guess... more or less reliably. So it is a platform that just invites "strawmans" and other similar arguments. In my experience, Twitter makes for excellent practice in how to try to express a point in a concise manner, then try to quickly figure out what other people actually understood about what you said. It is generally not possible to have a debate on this platform, but that's not its purpose anyway. I find it much more interesting to figure out why several people will understand the same tweet in completely different ways. Usually, it's because everyone starts from different sets of priors that they all consider obviously true, without being aware that their interpretation of whatever was said relies on these priors. I would recommend the books "How to have impossible conversations" about that, then Haidt's "The Righteous Mind" to understand the moral foundations of whoever you're talking to and how they differ from your own. Then of course awareness of the IQ bell curve, and since it's Twitter, a summary of the DSM-5, especially narcissistic and borderline.

> I want to know a way to quickly exit such situation and return to original debate

It's simple, you have to understand the other guy's point of view. Then realize you're talking about two different topics, and simply point it out, like I did in the first paragraph. Hopefully, that should clear things up.

Quite often when I or the other guy did that, it worked nicely. But you shouldn't be married to your point, after all, if you're wrong, it's an opportunity to learn something.

If the other guy is prone to emotional arguments, then that will be your job.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thanks for a great first answer!

Comment: @Carl and bobflux, this is in no way a 'great first answer', as it doesn't meet the [citation expectations](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3583/1599) for this site. Claims in answers should be backed up, preferably with research or otherwise personal experience. Also, bobflux wrote another answer first, in which they did manage to meet those expectations, so that would be their 'good first answer'.

Comment: Things like 'this happens quite often' should be backed up, how often does research state this happens? Or how often does this happen between you and others? Are you then the person making that mistake, or do others do so? And for the last section, when you say that doing specific things is a good way to handle a certain situation, quote research that shows the specific  tactic works, or describe your personal experience using it (what did you do, how did others react).

Comment: I could add a bit more details, yes. I'm curious how successful you are at enforcing that rule.

Comment: @bobflux, thanks for pointing, I chose a poor example, I can give a simpler situation, A: government should ban fertilizer subsidy as it is unproductive and this is acknowledged by IMF since 1990s
B: Oh that means you don't care about farmers, I know a farmer Mr. Mike, do you want Mr. Mike to suffer?
Now note that there is an opportunity cost with each government expense if government spends on unhealthy agricultural subsidies, it spends less on subsidizing higher education, so I can put one of my debt-loaded college friend Mr. Mike2 and say that does B want him to suffer

Comment: @bobflux continued here, now my essence is that regardless of any opinion one holds, it is always easy to find at least one person who will suffer due to it and then use that person's name as a human shield, but when both parties do it then discussion gets stalled, I am very sure there must be a name for this kind of fallacy and wanted to ask that name, but I am curious if your first point is holding still in this example, then I will have to think about that first

Comment: Yeah that's a better example. I'd say that shows the other person's moral foundations are focused on care/harm (see Haidt "The Righteous Mind") so it overrides their reasoning. Add r-selection, because this person thinks resources are unlimited and ignores the fact subsidies come from taxes and therefore harm taxpayers. Being unaware of that, we can't know how they stand on Fairness. Also no information on IQ. So I would start with a practical example: "Suppose I give you €1000, choose who will receive it as subsidy." Then inquire and find out about how they think.

Comment: Also offer to keep €1000 and hire a contractor to fix your roof, so if they take the money, they harm the contractor. I mean find out whether they think resources are infinite or not (r/K selection, magical thinking) whether they think they know enough to be in charge of deciding who gets the subsidy, how they decide, etc. 'Cause you're saying "human shield", okay, but that means you think about resources as finite (K-selection) and focus more on other moral foundations like fairness. From this priors, your conclusion is logical.

Comment: For example, if resources are infinite and we can print as much money as we want without consequences (yay!) then the other guy's argument is absolutely logical. If money is free, why wouldn't you give it to the farmer? I mean, as François Hollande said, "it's free because the State is paying for it." In this frame of mind, according to this psychological profile, you are evil for not giving the subsidies, and it makes perfect sense...

Comment: @bobflux, you didn't tag me so I couldn't see earlier.
Thanks a lot for detailed analysis, I understand now how to tackle this situation, also as you pointed out correctly, I was assuming situations that are zero-sum game that needs to be kept in mind. Also thanks for pointing to The Righteous Mind, terms like r/K selection, magical thinking